# Creating typescript interface from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Is there a way to import a JSON object into a Typescript program so that it is automatically strongly typed and constant?

So if I have this code in `person.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Steven",
  "eyeColor": "brown"
}
```

I want to be able to import it to a Typescript program as such:

```
// personTest.ts
const person = require('person.json');
console.log(person.name); // This should be fine
console.log(person.age);  // This should cause a compile-time error, because this property is not defined
```

Comment: have you tried using ESM ? `import person from 'person.json'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this on tsconfig.json

```
{

   ... //prev code

   "resolveJsonModule": true, 

}
```

then you can use ESM modules to import json file and it will be auto typed the object values

```
import person from './person.json' //be sure from the json path
```